# How to store and locate wsdl file in a google clould module using android studio

Tags: android, web-services, wsdl, google-cloud-endpoints, wsimport

I have been able to create java classes in my google clould module in android studio from wsdl file located in a remote server using `wsimport` tool. however, the remote `soap:address` is not complete which makes all my request to the server to fail. it looks like this

`<wsdl:port name="l_check" binding="tns:L_binding">
         <soap:address location="l_check_server.php" />
      </wsdl:port>`

Error that am getting on the client side is

`javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Unsupported endpoint address: l_check_server.php`

To solve this, i have downloaded the `wsdl` file and tried to put it in `webapp` folder using `wsimport` tool.

`wsimport -wsdllocation ./src/main/java/webapp/Check.wsdl`

**But this does not create a copy of the wsdl file in the specified folder** only setting the value in

```
    @WebServiceClient(name = "l_check_Service", targetNamespace = "tns:ns", wsdlLocation = "./src/main/java/webapp/Check.wsdl")
public class LCheckService extends Service {
    private final static URL LCHECKSERVICE_WSDL_LOCATION;
    private final static WebServiceException L_EXCEPTION;
    private final static QName LCHECKSERVICE_QNAME = new QName("tns:ns", "l_check_Service");

    static {
        LCHECKSERVICE_WSDL_LOCATION = com.c.p.s.LCheckService.class.getResource("./src/main/java/webapp/Check.wsdl");
        WebServiceException e = null;
        if (LNMOCHECKOUTSERVICE_WSDL_LOCATION == null) {
            e = new WebServiceException("Cannot find './src/main/java/webapp/Check.wsdl' wsdl. Place the resource correctly in the classpath.");
        }
        L_EXCEPTION = e;
    }
```

I decided to manually copy the wsdl file to the specified location.
When tried to make requests, i get the below exception

```
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Cannot find './src/main/java/webapp/Check.wsdl' wsdl. Place the resource correctly in the classpath.
```

How can i correctly place the wsdl file and get rid of the exception above?

or if possible, can i programmatically set soap address to the correct endpoint without downloading the wsdl file?

The correct soap address is `https://www.xxxx.co.xx/l_check_server.php`

**EDIT**

This is a cloud module that will be deployed to google app engine.

Comment: You realize that random files in /src are NOT part of the app that downloads to the file, right?  If you want to put it in the apk, it needs to be a resource in assets.

Comment: @GabeSechan it is a backend module which will be deployed to google app engine